# Custom default ImageSize while allowing inheriting

Tags: graphics, notebooks, options, inheritance, default

When displaying graphics in the Mathematica front end, and leaving `ImageSize` at the default, the result will always keep its previous size.

For example,

- `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 5}]` produces an output 360 pixels wide (the default size).
- Resize the plot with the mouse to make it bigger.
- Change the input to `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]` and re-evaluate it.
- The output figure remains at its manually set size and won't revert to 360 pixels wide.

If we were to use `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 5}, ImageSize -> 500]` instead, then the size of the output would be re-set to 500 pixels every time this command is re-evaluated.

`ImageSize -> Inherited` will generally allow this behaviour.

**Question:**

How can I create a function that will output graphics at sizes larger than 360 pixels by default, yet when re-sizing the output manually and re-evaluating the function, the manually set size will be kept?

I do not wish to change the default output size for other functions.

Comment: Does this work?: Edit the stylesheet, create a style `"Graphics"`; in the Options inspector, change the `ImageSize` setting under `GraphicsBoxOptions` to `500` (or whatever).  Alternatively, create a new style `"Foo"` and use `BaseStyle -> "Foo"` in your `Graphics`.

Comment: Maybe the second alternative `"Foo"` is what you're after.  The first changes it for all `Graphics`. -- Actually, `Plot[..., BaseStyle -> {GraphicsBoxOptions -> {ImageSize -> 500}}]` seems to work.  (Maybe?)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Nice work Michael.  I was just trying to figure out how scope `GraphicsBoxOptions` when I saw your comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The option `GraphicsBoxOptions -> {ImageSize -> 500}` can be set for the plot in several ways.  (The option [`PreserveImageOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PreserveImageOptions.html) is the one that controls what happens when the output cell is replaced. By default, the current size in output cell is preserved.)

#### Stylesheet

One can create a new style, say, `"LargeImageSize"` by editing the stylesheet (menu Format > Edit Stylesheet...) and entering name `LargeImageSize` into the "Enter a style name:" input field and pressing return.  The select the style cell and open the Option Inspector (menu Format > Option Inspector...).  In the search field of the Option Inspector, enter `GraphicsBoxOptions` and look for `ImageSize`.  Edit the option to the desired size.

Alternatively, the cell expression in the stylesheet (menu Cell > Show Expression) can be edited to look like this:

```
Cell[StyleData["LargeImageSize"],
 MenuSortingValue->10000,
 GraphicsBoxOptions->{ImageSize->500}]
```

Then the style can be used with `Plot` and other `Graphics` using the `BaseStyle` option:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 5}, BaseStyle -> "LargeImageSize"]
```

#### Using BaseStyle directly

One need not deal with stylesheets.  One can pass the option directly through `BaseStyle`:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 5}, BaseStyle -> {GraphicsBoxOptions -> {ImageSize -> 500}}]
```

#### Using Style

One can also use `Style` to post-process the graphics.  Either

```
Style[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 5}], "LargeImageSize"]
```

or

```
Style[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 5}], GraphicsBoxOptions -> {ImageSize -> 500}]
```